# VBA Regex: from last used row, in a column,get count of a matched pattern between another pattern

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm new to VBA using regex. On a worksheet, I have a column with cells that have several specific names and between these names are several qualifiers. I need help to put together a VBA/macro code using regex to loop through the column and get the counts of the qualifiers between names and put the count value to the cell on the right of the name. The names all start with uppercase letters while the qualifiers start with  a lower case letter. So i'm using ^[A-Z]* to match the names and ^[a-z]* for the qualifiers. Each value is in separate cells and the occurrences are random. So far I can only get total count of all qualifiers.  I appreciate the help.

[image]

Comment: So it seems you're already achieving your goal. Or what's your issue?

Comment: read appropriate range into an array and redim to have an additional column and loop backwards through rows. Have a counter you + 1 to each time (left,1) of value to test is lcase (you can use the ascii value). When you enounter an UCASE then write counter value to the array for that row and reset counter to 0. Continue looping. Write out array to sheet.

Comment: Redim preserve to keep values I should have typed and use LEFT$

Comment: Thanks for the comments, sorry for the confusion, the bottom pic is what I''m actually trying to achieve. I just don't know how to put it in code.

Comment: Why VBA?  You could also use worksheet formulas.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I'm new to using scripts on excel TBH. So far I've been able to put together a VBA/macro script to format the raw data I upload to this sheet and have it reformatted to this point. Now, I just can't figure out how to get the counts like I need to on the second image. If there's a way with worksheet formulas I can incorporate into it to automate the count process, I'm open to it. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose if you are already using VBA for some of it, you might as well use it for the rest. But you've not posted any of your code, or indicate where in your code you're having a problem, so it's hard to know what changes you need to make in what you have.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Like instead of RegEx

Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

'START ****************************************************************** START'
' Title:        Count Owners                                                   '
' Purpose:      Counts the number of cells containing a string starting with   '
'               a lower-case character below a cell containing a string        '
'               starting with an upper-case character and writes the result    '
'               to the same row of the string starting with the upper-case     '
'               character, in another (specified) column.                      '
'******************************************************************************'
Sub CountOwners()

    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"   ' Worksheet Name
    Const rowHeader As Long = 3         ' Header Row
    Const colOwner As Long = 2          ' Owner Column Number
    Const colCount As Long = 3          ' Count Column Number

    Dim rng As Range                    ' Owner Column, Owner Column Range,
                                        ' Count Column Range
    Dim vntOwner As Variant             ' Owner Array
    Dim vntCount As Variant             ' Count Array
    Dim LneRinC As Long                 ' Last Non-Empty Row in Owner Column
    Dim UB As Long                      ' Arrays Last Element Count
    Dim lngOwner As Long                ' Current Owner Element (Row)
    Dim lngCount As Long                ' (Current) Owner Count(er)
    Dim i As Long                       ' First Arrays Element Counter
    Dim j As Long                       ' Second Arrays Element Counter
    Dim strChar As String * 1           ' Current Char

    ' IN WORKSHEET

    ' Define Owner Column.
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).Columns(colOwner)
    ' Using the Find method, try to define Owner Column Range.
    Set rng = rng.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    ' Check if no data in Owner Column.
    If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo NoData
    ' Calculate Last Non-Empty Row in Owner Column.
    LneRinC = rng.Row
    ' Check if no Owners in Owner Column Range.
    If LneRinC <= rowHeader Then GoTo NoOwners
    ' Define Owner Column Range.
    Set rng = rng.Parent.Cells(rowHeader + 1, colOwner).Resize(LneRinC - rowHeader)
    ' Write values of Owner Column Range to Owner Array.
    vntOwner = rng

    ' IN ARRAYS

    ' Define Arrays Last Element Count
    UB = UBound(vntOwner)
    ' Resize Count Array (vntCount) to the size of Owner Array (vntOwner).
    ReDim vntCount(1 To UB, 1 To 1)
    ' Loop through elements of Owner Array.
    For i = 1 To UB
        ' Write first characterg of current element in Owner Array
        ' to Current Char.
        strChar = Left$(vntOwner(i, 1), 1)
        ' Check if current char is an uppercase character.
        If strChar Like "[A-Z]" Then
            ' Assign the value of the current row of Owner Array
            ' to Current Owner Element (Row).
            lngOwner = i
            ' Reset Current Owner Element.
            lngCount = 0
            ' Loop through the rest of the elements in Owner Array.
            For j = i + 1 To UB
                ' Write first character of current element in Owner Array
                ' to Current Char.
                strChar = Left$(vntOwner(j, 1), 1)
                ' Check if Current Char is an uppercase letter.
                If strChar Like "[A-Z]" Then
                    ' Reset First Arrays Element Counter.
                    i = j - 1
                    Exit For
                Else
                    ' Check if Current Char is a lowercase letter.
                    If strChar Like "[a-z]" Then
                        ' Increase (Current) Owner Counter.
                        lngCount = lngCount + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            ' Write value of (Current) Owner Counter to Count Array.
            vntCount(lngOwner, 1) = lngCount
        End If
    Next

    ' IN WORKSHEET

    ' Define Count Column Range.
    Set rng = rng.Offset(, colCount - colOwner)
    ' Write values of Count Array to Count Column Range.
    rng = vntCount

ProgramError:

Exit Sub

NoData:
    MsgBox "There is no data in Owner column (" & colOwner & ")."
    GoTo ProgramError

NoOwners:
    MsgBox "There are no Owners in Owner column (" & colOwner & ")."
    GoTo ProgramError

End Sub
'******************************************************************************'
' Remarks:    Values not starting with alpha characters are not counted.       '
'             Owner Column Range doesn't have to start with an Owner.          '
'             Owner Column Range can end with an Owner; the count will be 0.   '
'END ********************************************************************** END'
```

Comment: I appreciate the code, however, I'm not getting any outcomes. It ran with no errors, but I didn't see any output.  Any idea what would be wrong?

Comment: for some reason the vntCount value is returning blank. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @user13282050:'Adjust the values in the constants section' means that you have to adjust the first 4 values in the code. Maybe you have 'Sheet1' but have the columns in another sheet. Change 'wsName'. The header row (is the 3rd row) and the columns are adjusted to your posted picture: 2 stands for column 'B' and 3 for column 'C'. Here is a link to [my file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QeEw-JYnzDtYBlyWF9jXJAcdvhhGk-k1). You can download it and try it yourself. See the change in the yellow column after clicking the Count button..

Comment: I did change the constants to align with my worksheet but didn't get any counts displayed. I created a test worksheet with a sample of my data to match your constants, no result either. I downloaded your sheet and did see it worked just fine. The code is doing exactly what I need, but only if I manually type my data into your worksheet. But doesn't work if I copy and paste the same said sample data into your sheet. So that tells me it's not a data issue. Is there a setting associated with your code that I may be missing on my worksheet?

Comment: @user13282050: You might have an 'invisible' character or a space in front of e.g. Steve. If Steve is in B4, try the formula =CODE(LEFT(B4,1)) somewhere in the same row (or not) and it should return 83. The character codes for A-Z are 65-90 and for a-z are 97-122. If it isn't 83, you might get rid of it with the TRIM, RIGHT or MID functions in Excel. It's not productive to change it in the VBA code.If you can provide a link to your file, I could probably fix the issue.

Comment: That was it! there was a space in front of all the usernames, the qualifiers were fine strangely enough. It was a data issue after all. After removing the spaces, it worked perfectly! Thanks so much and high five from me!

Comment: Hello @VBasic2008, could you assist me in extending your code a bit further? I am trying to get the count of qualifiers per department now. That is loop through owner column and capture the count of qualifiers between each department and append it to the column D.